# Is there any effective way to retrieve the number of celery task currently doing in a specific queue?

Tags: rabbitmq, celery, django-celery, celery-task

I want to know the number of celery tasks currently doing and waiting tasks.

However, all of the celery inspect command shows the incorrect results and It seems not easy to use them.

My celery info is like below.

```
- ** ---------- [config]
- ** ---------- .> app:         myapp:0x7f72b15195c0
- ** ---------- .> transport:   amqp://guest:**@localhost:5672//
- ** ---------- .> results:     redis://localhost/
- *** --- * --- .> concurrency: 2 (prefork)
-- ******* ---- .> task events: OFF (enable -E to monitor tasks in this worker)
--- ***** ----- 
 -------------- [queues]
                .> myqueue_1     exchange=myqueue_1(direct) key=myqueue_1
```

I've tried to count the number by the below way.

```
def get_queue_task_count(queue_name):

    inspector = Inspect(app=celery_app)
    active_tasks = inspector.active()

    specific_queue_routing_keys = set()
    for worker, tasks in active_tasks.items():
        for task in tasks:
            if task['delivery_info']['routing_key'] == queue_name:
                specific_queue_routing_keys.add(task['delivery_info']['routing_key'])

    return len(specific_queue_routing_keys)
```

In this code, I expected this func could return the num of tasks currently doing in the specific queue,
but every time I call this func, the inspector.active() returns different info and I think it is because other queues running on the same server.(queue 1, queue2, queue3.. I want to know only about the tasks in the queue1!)

In this situation, Is there any effective way to get the information of the specific queue?